# Error installing coco-0.4.0.tar.gz in Python: "Command errored out with exit status 1"

Tags: python, pip, coco

I am trying to install coco-0.4.0.tar.gz in python through `pip install`, but I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\brene\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\brene\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wbchu6pa\\coco\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\brene\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wbchu6pa\\coco\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\brene\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wbchu6pa\coco\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\brene\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wbchu6pa\coco\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\brene\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wbchu6pa\coco\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        import coco
      File "C:\Users\brene\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wbchu6pa\coco\coco.py", line 18, in <module>
        from docopt import docopt
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docopt'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Kindly post the command used to install it. Where does that file come from?

Answer (score 1):

[`coco` 0.4.0](https://pypi.org/project/coco/), the last release was at Jan 5, 2013. The package announces compatibility with Python 2.6 and 2.7.

`setup.py` imports module `coco` (from the file `coco.py`) which imports `docopt` without installing it.

My resolution is: the package is buggy, old, outdated and abandoned. Not recommended for any use.

If you want to try it anyway — first install `docopt`:

```
pip install docopt
```